# How to make sure that sidebar fills page (Angular + ng-bootstrap + angular material)

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

Currently my side navigation bar only sizes to fit the activated link, instead of showing all the links. Is there a way to fix it so that it shows all the links fully all the time?

[image: first link active]

[image: last link active]

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light" style="width: 280px;">
      <ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-pills" orientation="vertical">
        <li *ngFor="let link of links" ngbNavItem="{{ link.name }}">
          <a ngbNavLink routerLink='{{ link.link }}'>{{ link.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button></p>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Set `height:100%` to the sidenav container?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was setting `height:100%` in the sidenav container as Vishnudev posted.